# Column 'CM.PfmFolder.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Getting Column 'CM.PfmFolder.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Please suggest how can i reframe this query

```
 SELECT                     
 F.Id                    
,F.FolderNo                    
,F.FolderStatusDate
,(SELECT CodeDesc FROM CM.CodeTable WHERE Id = F.FolderStatusCode) 'FolderStatus'                    
,(SELECT CodeDesc FROM CM.CodeTable WHERE Id = F.FolderLocationCode) 'Location'                    
,F.Volume                    
,F.SDExhibits                    
,F.Cost                    
,F.Remarks                    
 FROM CM.PfmFolder F WITH(NOLOCK, INDEX(IX)) INNER JOIN                    
(                    
 CM.PfmFolderMstIpMap MAP WITH(NOLOCK, INDEX(ix_FF))                  
 INNER JOIN  CM.MstIp IP WITH(NOLOCK) ON MAP.MstIpFK = IP.Id                   
 AND IP.RegistryCode = @RegistryCode                    
 AND IP.DeletedBy IS NULL                      
 AND MAP.DeletedBy IS NULL                      
)                    
ON MAP.PfmFolderFK = F.Id                    
AND F.DeletedBy IS NULL      
AND (                    
 F.FolderStatusDate >= @FolderStatusDateFrom                    
 AND F.FolderStatusDate < @FolderStatusDateTo                    
 )                    
AND (                    
  @FolderLocationCode IS NULL                    
  OR @FolderLocationCode = @GUID_EMPTY                    
  OR F.FolderLocationCode = @FolderLocationCode                    
 )                    
AND (                    
  @FolderStatusCode IS NULL                    
  OR @FolderStatusCode = @GUID_EMPTY                    
  OR F.FolderStatusCode = @FolderStatusCode                    
 )
 GROUP BY F.Id
```

Comment: `CM.PfmFolder F` CM is alias For PfmFolder or what?

Comment: All our tables are preceeded with CM, it's not alias. Its table name CM.PfmFolder, and F is alias for CM.PfmFolder

Comment: Have you tried without `GROUP BY F.Id`

Comment: without group by its working fine...but getting duplicate data. If i use distinct the query performance is very slow

Comment: You cant use Group by like that...You need to have all item in Select for using group by

Comment: Why was this question created when it is just part of the conversation of your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495604/restructure-query-without-using-distinct-keyword-in-sql-server ? I added a comment there stating that you needed to use all fields in the SELECT in the  GROUP BY, but that you really needed to provide the table schema and sample data in order to answer the real question of how to possible write the query without the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an aggregate function for other columns except ID, to get distinct valeus for each grouped F.Id.

You can also use the ranking functions to do so like this:

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT                     
 F.Id                    
,F.FolderNo                    
,F.FolderStatusDate
,(SELECT CodeDesc FROM CM.CodeTable WHERE Id = F.FolderStatusCode) 'FolderStatus'                    
,(SELECT CodeDesc FROM CM.CodeTable WHERE Id = F.FolderLocationCode) 'Location'                    
,F.Volume                    
,F.SDExhibits                    
,F.Cost                    
,F.Remarks,
Row_number() OVER(partition BY F.Id  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ASC) RN              
 FROM CM.PfmFolder F WITH(NOLOCK, INDEX(IX)) INNER JOIN                    
(                    
 CM.PfmFolderMstIpMap MAP WITH(NOLOCK, INDEX(ix_FF))                  
 INNER JOIN  CM.MstIp IP WITH(NOLOCK) ON MAP.MstIpFK = IP.Id                   
 AND IP.RegistryCode = @RegistryCode                    
 AND IP.DeletedBy IS NULL                      
 AND MAP.DeletedBy IS NULL                      
)                    
ON MAP.PfmFolderFK = F.Id                    
AND F.DeletedBy IS NULL      
AND (                    
 F.FolderStatusDate >= @FolderStatusDateFrom                    
 AND F.FolderStatusDate < @FolderStatusDateTo                    
 )                    
AND (                    
  @FolderLocationCode IS NULL                    
  OR @FolderLocationCode = @GUID_EMPTY                    
  OR F.FolderLocationCode = @FolderLocationCode                    
 )                    
AND (                    
  @FolderStatusCode IS NULL                    
  OR @FolderStatusCode = @GUID_EMPTY                    
  OR F.FolderStatusCode = @FolderStatusCode                    
 )
) AS T
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: T is alias of your Select Statement and RN is the alias of Row_Number

Comment: Great Query works fine but takes 16 seconds to execute 300K data. Is there any other way to optimize for better performance

Comment: May you try for CTE http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @user1030181 I have answered here too for your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496825/2118383

Answer (score 0):

You might also check your Join conditions and make sure that they're giving distinct results. Having these duplicates might be caused by these conditions.

MSM